# ØMQ C function (shared library / .dll) binding causing hard crash on zmq_init

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm trying to write an ABL binding for the [ØMQ C library](http://api.zeromq.org/2-2%3a_start), but am crashing the Procedure Editor for my [zmq_init](http://api.zeromq.org/2-2%3azmq-init) function binding.  I wrote a [binding for zmq_version](https://github.com/abevoelker/abl-zmq/blob/master/lib/zmq/zmq_version.p) without issue, so I assume it's not a .dll file problem.  Anyway, the C function prototype looks like this:

```
void *zmq_init (int io_threads);
```

The ABL code I've written is as follows:

```
PROCEDURE zmq_init EXTERNAL "libzmq.dll" CDECL:
  DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER num_threads AS LONG.
  DEFINE RETURN PARAMETER context_ptr AS MEMPTR.
END PROCEDURE.

DEF VAR mContext AS MEMPTR NO-UNDO.
RUN zmq_init(INPUT 0, OUTPUT mContext).
```

This particular function initializes a "0mq context" (potential problem: it's a thread pool) and returns a pointer to it.  Could the error be related to OpenEdge's non-threaded nature, even though I'm calling an external library and requesting 0 threads be allocated in the pool?

Running the code in Procedure Editor makes it crash with a Windows "Progress Client has stopped working" error with `Exception code: C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION` ([full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/2515526) here, although I don't always get a stack trace with info in it).

I've never done Windows C programming, but it looks like what I'd call a Segmentation Fault if I were on Unix using gcc (accessing protected memory).  Speaking of which, I'd in fact rather run this code on a Unix machine but apparently Progress only provides evaluation developer OE environments for Windows :(.

I've disabled DEP without success.  Is ABL trying to dereference the pointer when it returns from the library or something?  Surely there has to be a way to handle signatures with a return value of void* that get malloc'ed in the library call.

I've paged through [OpenEdge Development: Programming Interfaces](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dvpin/dvpin.pdf), Tom Bascom's [UNIX Shared Libraries](http://dbappraise.com/ppt/shlib.pptx) PowerPoint, and some other PowerPoint called [OpenEdge in an LDAP World](http://www.psdn.com/ak_download/media/exch_audio/2007/DEV/DEV-4_Jacobs.ppt) that has some code samples but don't see anything obvious that I'm missing.

I'm on OpenEdge 10.2B, Windows 7 64-bit, however using the 32-bit version of OpenEdge as that's my only option for evaluation software.  Anyone got a license I could borrow for compiling/running this code on CentOS? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the error be related to OpenEdge's non-threaded nature, even though I'm calling an >external library and requesting 0 threads be allocated in the pool?

I ran into the same problem several times (Progress Client has stopped working) while i was working on some c# methods (called via clr bridge) in which I used threads.
Hiding the threads from progress by using some c# library classes(AsyncOperation,AsyncCallback) solved the problem, but most attempts caused the progress runtime to stop.

Related to .net the progress help states "You cannot use System.Threading.Thread, or any derived class — ABL is single-threaded."

I know that calling c# methods via clr bridge is completely different from invoking c libraries but maybe our problems are caused by the single threaded nature of OpenEdge.

Comment: Yep, I believe you are correct. On the official OpenEdge forum there is some [example code](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/message/136057#135953) using the .NET binding over the CLR bridge that apparently works fine. I guess that will be the only way to get 0MQ working with ABL. It's a pity, because it would have been a very clean way of doing IPC compared to the ugly `SOCKET` or named pipe methods. Thankfully I don't have to write ABL anymore so it doesn't stress me.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing **PERSISTENT** keyword when you are declaring your procedures.

Please try the following code:

**zmq.p**

```
&SCOPED DLLNAME 'libzmq.so'
PROCEDURE zmq_init EXTERNAL {&DLLNAME} CDECL PERSISTENT:
    DEF INPUT  PARAMETER NumThreads AS LONG.
    DEF RETURN PARAMETER Context AS MEMPTR.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE zmq_term EXTERNAL {&DLLNAME} CDECL PERSISTENT:
    DEF INPUT  PARAMETER Context  AS MEMPTR.
    DEF RETURN PARAMETER ResultStatus AS LONG.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE zmq_version EXTERNAL {&DLLNAME} CDECL PERSISTENT:
    DEF OUTPUT PARAMETER major AS LONG.
    DEF OUTPUT PARAMETER minor AS LONG.
    DEF OUTPUT PARAMETER patch AS LONG.
END PROCEDURE.
```

---

**check_zmq.p**

```
DEF VAR Zmq AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR MajorVersion AS INT NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR MinorVersion AS INT NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR PatchVersion AS INT NO-UNDO.

DEF VAR CallStatus AS INT NO-UNDO.

DEF VAR ZmqContext AS MEMPTR NO-UNDO.

RUN zmq.p PERSISTENT SET Zmq.

RUN zmq_version IN Zmq ( OUTPUT MajorVersion, OUTPUT MinorVersion, OUTPUT PatchVersion ).
MESSAGE MajorVersion MinorVersion PatchVersion.

RUN zmq_init IN Zmq ( 1, OUTPUT ZmqContext ).
RUN zmq_term IN Zmq ( ZmqContext, OUTPUT CallStatus ).
MESSAGE CallStatus.

FINALLY:
    IF VALID-HANDLE(Zmq) THEN
         DELETE PROCEDURE Zmq.
END FINALLY.
```

Comment: Interesting, I will give this a look later this week if I have time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed your code from github and changed the MEMPTR variables to INT64.  This allowed it to run without crashing (10.2b05 32-bit on 64-bit Windows 7).  Since the memory is being handled by zeromq, I think this is a safe way to handle the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I still seem to be getting the same behavior.  Are you using the 32-bit .dll?  I can't bind against the 64-bit .dll (`Could not load DLL procedure libzmq.dll. (3258)`) so have been using the 32-bit one.  Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/81b5b6f37b66f60efaff) of what I'm doing... please let me know what you're doing differently!

Comment: Nope, doesn't work with either `RETURN` or `OUTPUT`. Can you consistently get this to work? It doesn't crash every time for me, just most of the time.